# What is the meaning of "burke a school" in Anticipations?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang, twentieth-century-english

In [*Anticipations*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/19229/19229-h/19229-h.htm) (1901), chapter 9, in the middle of a long passage, H. G. Wells wrote (referring to a personification of Jewish people):

> ...  He is a remnant and legacy of mediævalism, a sentimentalist perhaps, but no furtive plotter against the present progress of things.   He was the mediæval Liberal; his persistent existence gave the lie to Catholic pretensions all through the days of their ascendency, and to-day he gives the lie to all our yapping "nationalisms," and sketches in his dispersed sympathies the coming of the world-state. He has never been known to burke a school. Much of the Jew's usury is no more than social scavenging. ...

What does "burke a school" mean here?  It must be a reference to the serial killer William Burke, but I am not sure what exact act the phrase implies.

Answer (score 9):

It's outdated Victorian "slang"...

> **burke** (verb, transitive)
> LITERALLY
> To murder, in the same manner or for the same purpose as (mass murderer) [Burke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burke_and_Hare_murders) did; to kill secretly by suffocation or strangulation, or for the purpose of selling the victim's body for dissection.
> FIGURATIVELY
> To smother, ‘hush up’, suppress quietly. Also, to evade, to shirk, to avoid.

---

I don't *know* exactly how that usage applies to Jews and school, but I think Wells meant that Jews would never allow a "social good" such as a ***school*** to be forced to close (be metaphorically "suffocated") for lack of funds.

In Wells's time, moneylending was the stereotypical occupation of Jews, and I've no doubt Wells himself was concerned that many "good schools" were under-resourced and at risk of closure. But that's just my guess.

Comment: Yes, but which if any of these meanings applies to "burke a school"?  Nothing seems to quite fit.

Comment: Wells's attitude towards Jews was peculiar and mercurial, to say the least, but although the phrasing strikes me as nauseating today, I think your cited text is supposed to be complimentary. So I guess he means "a Jew" would never refuse to lend money to a ***school*** (even though there might be a high risk that the school wouldn't be able to make the repayments in full). Jews wouldn't see a school die for lack of funds.

Comment: But that's just my guess - the usage is no longer current, nor is the surrounding social context (attitudes to Jews have changed in the *Western* world, and Jews are no longer kept out of all professions except moneylending, for example).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Much as I love to read Wells, I am greatly troubled that he wrote things like this: _This thing, this euthanasia of the weak and the sensual, is possible. I have little or no doubt that in the future it will be planned and achieved._ He wrote of, _boys and girls and youth and maidens, full of zest and new life, full of an abundant joyful receptivity . . . helpers behind us in the struggle._ However... _And for the rest, these swarms of black and brown and dingy white and yellow people who do not come into the needs of efficiency . . . I take it they will have to go._

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I didn't know *any* "children of colour" as a child, but I always found Wells's "colonialist" attitude nauseating. I was a fanatical reader of sci-fi as a child, but I never liked much of his stuff, because it was too "antiquated".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - my uncle was an avid reader of science fiction, and had been buying and keeping magazines and paperback novels since the end of the war. I was a furiously precocious child, and was reading Van Vogt, Bester, Blish, Heinlein, etc from the age of 7. He bestowed his collection on me. I wish I still had it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: "Those were the days, my friend". You're just reminding me of how diligently I used to scour the shelves in the local library when I was 9 or 10, looking for any new Gollancz books. (Their "hi-vis yellow jacket" books were nearly always new sci-fi, and they certainly stood out for *me*! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Me too! I found _Who?_ by Algis Budrys that way. I can still see it on the shelf in my mind's eye. 60 years ago.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I found a copy of his collected short stories in a jumble sale and was fascinated by them. I still feel creepy from reading 'In the Avu Observatory', I still feel sorry for poor Weena, and I was impressed at age 10 by the Raymond Massey speech in 'Things to Come'. _Rest enough for the individual man. Too much and too soon, and we call it death. But for Man, no rest and no ending. He must go on, conquest beyond conquest. First this little planet and its winds and ways. And then all the laws of mind and matter that restrain him..._

Answer (score 7):

I don't know this work but the work was either abridged or enlarged and the version cited in the question is missing the explanation:

> He is a remnant and legacy of mediævalism, a sentimentalist perhaps, but no **furtive plotter** against the present progress of things. He was the mediæval Liberal; his persistent existence gave the lie to Catholic pretensions all through the days of their ascendency, and to-day he gives the lie to all our yapping "nationalisms," and sketches in his dispersed sympathies the coming of the world state. He has never been known to burke a school: such a **malicious plot** as that associated with the name of the Lord Hugh Cecil, to rob the struggling adolescents of the poorer middle-class of their one poor chance of education, by burking the Higher Grade Board Schools, would certainly be beneath the mental and moral level of the average Whitechapel Jew. [my emphasis]

https://mssp.byu.edu/title/anticipations-of-the-reaction-of-mechanical-and-scientific-progress-upon-human-life-and-thought/

Comment: It appears that the reference to Lord Hugh Cecil was included in the original serialization in the _Fortnightly Review_ of _Anticipations_, and the first publication of it as a book, but was left out of subsequent editions.

Comment: It appears the circumspect phrase "such a malicious plot *as that associated with the name* of "Lord Hugh Cecil" didn't satisfy the concerns of somebody.

Comment: Whilst this is incredibly useful information ... what does "burke" mean?

Comment: @Fattie: It means to take surreptitious steps to "kill" something such that your involvement remains hidden -- and that's "kill" in a figurative sense, as in to thwart or suppress, to see that something does not come to fruition or thrive.  The meaning comes from the criminal Burke who suffocated his victims to hide the fact that they had been murdered, and then sold them to medical students for dissection.  See the answer by FumbleFingers.

Answer (score 3):

**[Burke](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burke)** (Merriam-Webster):

> to suppress quietly or indirectly

After, as the OP correctly deduces, [William Burke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burke_and_Hare_murders), who smothered his victims.  To "burke a school" would be to supress it, get it to close down, without actively campaigning against it.  As we're dealing with anti-Semetism, this would probably be by financial methods, such as refusing to extend credit to the governing body.

Comment: The idea that Jews *might* surreptitiously force a school to close sounds ridiculous to me, so it doesn't make sense that Wells would ***explicitly refute*** that action. It's much more likely a reference to preventing the school from "dying" by lending it money (which from Wells's point of view was essentially what Jews did - lend money).